# Issues with deserialization of generic c# class from mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics, deserialization

I am having trouble using Mongodb and c# to de-serialize an object that uses generics. The object represents all the events that could happen in the application that I am developing(I am using event-sourcing). All the events will be stored in the same MongoDB collection and the state of the application will be reconstructed from the events when the server runs.

The EventDocument class is shown below.

```cs
/// `TPayload` is the type of the actual event type that will be stored in the database.
public sealed class EventDocument<TPayload, TId> where TPayload : class where TId : struct, IComparable
{
    [BsonId] 
    public EventId Id { get; init; } = EventId.Next();

    public TId AggregateId { get; init; }

    public TPayload Payload { get; init; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; init; }
    public UserId CreatedBy { get; init; }

    public int Version { get; init; }
}
```

Adding events to the database works as you can see in the image. The type `TPayload` is converted to `Object` in the mongoDB database.
[Mongodb data stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0RJu.png)

```json
{
  "_id": "345f206f-c96d-4472-8707-567f51b78d87",
  "Payload": Object {
     // payload 
  },
  // other attributes are omitted. 
}
```

The problem arises when I want to reconstruct the payload from the events stored mongodb.

```cs
public async Task<List<EventDocument<TPayload, TId>>> GetAllAsync()
{
    // crashes here because Mongodb serializer does not know how to convert the object
    List<EventDocument<TPayload, TId>> allEvents = await _events.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
    return allEvents;
}
```

I tried to create a filtering condition to only return the events of a certain type but the filtering condition did not work (It returned 0 elements after the filter).

```cs
var filter = Builders<EventDocument<TPayload, TId>>.Filter.Eq("Payload", typeof(TPayload).FullName);
await _events.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

I know that I can remove the TPayload generic type and have inheritance for the payload by using `BsonDiscriminator` and `BsonKnownTypes` attributes.
I want to ask if there is an easy solution for the deserialization problem **without** changing the structure of the `EventDocument` class(It will require a lot of refactoring to change)

I am still a beginner in using Mongodb with C#, so please take that into account when answering the question.
Thank you.

Comment: Use `"{ }"` or `FilterDefinition<YourClass>.Empty` instead of `_ => true`

Comment: I still does not work unfortunately. I get this error 
`An error occurred while deserializing the Payload property of class: Element 'Question' does not match any field or property of class Voted`.
I have `VoteEvents` that do not have the field `Question` but also `QuestionEvents` that have the field `Question`.